# Boost 1.41.0 : boost::locale alternative?

Tags: c++, boost, centos, centos6

In my CentOS 6.9 environment boost-devel refers to Boost 1.4**1**.0 library.

The problem is that *boost:locale* is not available for my dates calculations relative to a particular timezone, as *boost:locale* seems to come with Boost 1.4**8**.0.

Is there an alternative to do things like that with 1.41 (or an alternative of Boost) ?

```
// adding a day to now with timezone in mind
std::locale::global(...a specific locale...);
date_time now;
now = now + period:day();
```

Comment: Here is another timezone library that is quite complete:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html  However I don't know if it would work for your older environment.  It requires C++11's `<chrono>`.  Here is example code showing adding 1 day to a local time in an arbitrary time zone across a daylight saving change:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#local_arithmetic

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use std::locale available in c++98 on Centos 6.

See an example of parsing a locale format time into std::time here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/time_get/get_date/

Once you have your time in std::time you should be able to add hours/minutes/seconds etc individually, or you could convert to time since epoch and make calculations that way.